# Calling Objective-C method from C++ using template and command pattern

Tags: c++, objective-c, templates, command-pattern

I was not able to find it on stackoverflow. I have come up with this approach. Please suggest if there is any better way to do it.
Code:

The C++ class:

```
struct CmdObj{
    int value;  
    ...
};

class CallBack{
public:
    virtual void operator()(CmdObject &cmdObj) = 0; 
};

#ifdef __OBJC__
//For objective c class
template <class T> 
class CallBackImpl: public CallBack{

public:
    CallBackImpl(T* _object, SEL _method): object(_object), method(_method){}

    virtual void operator()(CmdObject &cmdObj){ 
        NSValue *anObj = [NSValue value:&cmdObj withObjCType:@encode(CmdObject)];
        [object  performSelector:method withObject:anObj];
    }    

private:
    SEL method;
    T* object;
};
#endif
```

The use of this class in Objective C:

```
    @interface Callee{
        CallBack *delegate;
    }

    - (void) callbackMethod:(NSValue *) anObj;
    @end

    @implementation
    - (id) initCallee{
        delegate = new CallBackImpl<Callee>(self, @selector(callbackMethod:);
    }
    - (void) callbackMethod:(NSValue *) anObj
    {
        CmdObject cmdObj;
        [anObj getValue:&cmdObj];
        int value = cmdObj.value;
        ...
    }
    - (void) callDelegate: (NSInteger _value)
    {
        if(delegate == NULL ) return;
        CmdObject cmdObj;
        cmdObj.value = _value;

        (*delegate)(cmdObj);
    }
    @end
```

Comment: Please note that this `typedef struct` thing is not necessary in C++. A simple `struct CmdObj` will be enough.

Comment: I came from C background. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: I have a slightly different implementation...

Instead of @encode(CmdObject) I have @encode(CmdObject *).
On the other end where you retrieve the value, I have:

CmdObject *cmdObj = (CmdObject *)[anObj pointerValue];

Comment: Actually, I was thinking this morning: why do you need the type param T at all? I don't think it adds anything.

In the end, instead of value:withObjCType: I used valueWithPointer:&cmdObj. The other way I was getting some undesirable side effects of the object being copied (I think - didn't get too deep into it). So, I'm just serializing a pointer to the object instead, and passing that around.